# JDBC Query. Retrieving records based on an input from console.an error called SQL statement not ended properly

Tags: database, jdbc

I am trying to get a record from database student based on a query performed on the databased using an sql connection and a input of the record number from the user.

```
package com.sun.java;

      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.sql.Connection;
      import java.sql.Driver;
      import java.sql.DriverManager;
      import java.sql.SQLException;
      import java.sql.Statement;

      public class TableFetch {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Driver drv = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();

        DriverManager.registerDriver(drv);



        Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection ("url", "user", "password");

        System.out.println("Got the connection from DB" + con);

        System.out.println("kindly enter the sno of the record to fetch");

        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        int s9 = n.nextInt();

        String sql = "select * from student" + "WHERE sno =" + s9 + ";";
        Statement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.executeQuery(sql);

        n.close();
        }
        }
```

Comment: In place of url,user and password I have given url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:XE user = system and password = oracle. The error that I am getting is that SQL command not ended properly

Comment: Please post the error trace...

Comment: Try printing your sql statement to check the query formed using `+` is indeed what is expected.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: query posted by you will not work...print it to the console and the run it separately to verify the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement got error:

> String sql = "select * from student" + "WHERE sno =" + s9 + ";";

Please have space between `student` and `WHERE`

P/S: Sorry for unable to comment because I dont have enough points.

Comment: Hi I am sorry In my actual code I have not kept that ";" in the end. Without it also it gives the same error

Comment: Did you try to make it like below: String sql = "select * from student " + "WHERE sno =" + s9 + ";";

Comment: hey it worked. thanks. there was a space problem between student and where. also the ";" at the end of the sql query is not required.

Comment: If it work, could you please mark it as accepted answer. Otherwise, ppl will try to repeat the troubleshooting process again :)